# SEO - Changing a magento website theme would effect my ranking?

Tags: pagerank, google-ranking, template, theme

I have an **e-commerce website** built with **magento**.

i working on a new theme, and it is faster and more optimised then the old theme.

My question is would theme changing effect my ranking ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short: changing your theme very well might affect your rankings.**

This might be caused by (a combination of) the aspects below:

- The theme is likely to contain multiple changes to the way on-page elements like `h1` and `img` are placed in the source code.
- Perhaps it will even change the way that elements like `rel="canonical"` are handled.
- Also, the way in which pages are linked to each other (for instance via the main navigation) commonly changes between themes.
- Additionally, with a new theme you will also be loading different/more/less files (CSS, JS, images, videos, etc.) which could have an effect on your page loading time.
- Lastly, even the user experience will change because of the new theme. Given that Google is likely taking user experience metrics (such as bounce rate, time on site, etc.) into account these days, even that might have an impact on your SEO rankings.

Make sure you monitor any changes to your website before and after you're starting to use the new theme to make sure any issues to your website can be fixed afterwards.

Comment: While changing theme *could* affect SEO, I've done countless website redesign and theme changes that haven't changed rankings at all.

Comment: Fully agreed, I just wanted to emphasize the possibility that such changes _might_ impact SEO, even though it is 'just the layout' that changes.